# DLLImport in WPFApp not working (PInvokeStackImbalance)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created two C# applications, one is a WPF application and the other is a console application. Both have the same code in them (I have created the console application to test out the C# code and copied over into the real application, which is the WPF application).

The DLLImport I am using looks like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFileA(string lpFileName, long dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, uint lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

and gets called in code like this:

```
 Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 ModuleInformation mi = new ModuleInformation();
 IntPtr dllModule = GetModuleHandleA(dllName);

 GetModuleInformation(process.Handle, dllModule, out mi, (uint)(IntPtr.Size * 3));
 IntPtr baseAddress = mi.lpBaseOfDll;
 IntPtr dllFile = CreateFileA(dllPath, 0x80000000L, 1, 0, 3, 0, (IntPtr)0);
```

In the console application the code works perfectly fine, in the WPF app however I receive following error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'WpfApp1!WpfApp1.Class1::CreateFileA' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.'

I tried to change the calling convention, but the error did not change. Why does it work in the console application but not in the WPF application?

EDIT:
Now the same error happens for VirtualProtect:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, long flNewProtect, out IntPtr lpflOldProtect);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the exact declaration from [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr CreateFileA(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess access,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
    IntPtr securityAttributes,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes flagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr templateFile);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I've got the same problem for VirtualProtect now though...I edited the initial question so you can see the code. I searched on pinvoke for another declaration but could not find it.

Comment: nevermind, fixed it with the VirtualProtectEx declaration.